# How do I redirect from the old domain to the new domain via an alias on the DNS of the old domain, using the .htaccess of the new one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, alias, http-status-code-301

Sorry if that question title doesn't make any sense but it pretty much captures where I'm at with my confusion here.

So I've worked on a site that we'll call new-site.com that is going to be taking over from an existing site that we'll call old-site.com

There's no cross-over between the sites necessarily, but the owners don't want the sites to both exist at the same time so they want old-site.com to redirect to new-site.com which seems fairly straightforward.

My thought process for doing this would be to add a simple redirect rule to the htaccess file of old-site.com that just forwards everything to new-site.com, job done.

What is actually going to happen is that the developer of old-site.com is saying that what we need to do is to hold all the redirects for old-site.com in the htaccess file in the public folder of new-site.com and that he will then 'alias' the old-site.com domain over to new-site.com via the old domain DNS.

This is super confusing to me and a little out of my comfort zone and I'm not sure how I'd go about writing my redirects. Should I include the full domain name for old-site.com in there every time because otherwise surely I'll end up in a redirect loop if I don't use the domain name and I want to go from old-site.com/about-us to new-site.com/about-us?

I hope that makes sense and that some more experienced hands know what I need to do and can help me understand a little better?

Thank you

Comment: One things is redirecting requests to the old site, another thing is to change the DNS entry for the old site. You do either or. The first option requires to operate the old site in future, because that is there the redirections are implemented. That sounds like an issue. So changing the DNS entry for "old-site.com" to point to the same system as "new-site.com" makes sense. But in addition you need to respond to requests still using the old site's structure (bookmarks, google entries, ...). For _those_ requests you need to implement redirections on the new site.

Comment: Thanks Arkascha. How do I add the redirects for new-site.com in that instance?

would it be:

Redirect 301 old-site.com/about-us /about-us

or: 

Redirect 301 old-site.com/about-us new-site.com/about-us

or

Redirect 301 /about-us /about-us - This is what the old site dev says I should do.

Comment: Well, you need to redirect, not to rewrite, you want a permanent redirection and you need to redirect to a separate host if you want to implement those rules on the old site. Is that really what you want? Why?

Comment: I would suggest you change the DNS resolution of the old site to point to the new site, create a dummy virtual host for the old site where you can implement the redirection rules _if required_ until it is safe to switch it off. That leaves the new site clean of handling the old site's structure. And you are not depending on the maintainer of the old site.

Comment: If you can not set this up so that the old domain gets routed into its own Vhost, then you will need to use the `RewriteCond` directive to check on the host name of incoming requests.